# Stored Procedure Into Common Table Expression Workaround?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I need to essentially wrap a common table expression around the output from a stored procedure, obviously the stored procedure cannot be called directly from within the CTE so I am trying to find a workaround.

I have tried using `SELECT FROM OPENROWSET`, which initially looked like it solved the problem - however some of the stored procedures I need to call contain `sp_executesql` commands so it generates an error -

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC sp_executesql @SQL' in procedure 'sp_CustomerAndWorkers'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set."

I have also looked at `OPENQUERY`, but that doesn't allow parameters to be included.

Is there any other method I could consider? Would be be possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I won't know the columns for the temporary table until runtime, so it needs to be auto populated rather than created then filled. How would I fill it automatically without using OPENROWSET?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Temporary tables?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable
EXEC sp_executesql
```

Comment: I won't know the columns for the temporary table until runtime, so this is not an option. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user1948635 - if you won't know the columns until runtime, you're just going to continue to run into obstacles. A query with a CTE still has to have a single "shape" - a fixed set of columns, with specific names and types.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right, was hoping for a way to wrap all the view/proc calls in one so I could apply a security model around it, but I will look for a different approach. Thanks